# How to set a function to execute later in Javascript if it will take a long time?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
function wait() {
    let a = Date.now()
    while (Date.now() - a < 3000) {
        //loop
    }
    console.log('waiting ends...')
}
function start(){
    console.log('starts...')
    wait()
}
function end(){
    console.log('ends...')
}

start()
end()
```

How can I set wait() execute asynchronously that lead to a output of "starts..., ends..., waiting ends..." without apply setTimeout function to wait()?

Comment: `without apply setTimeout function to wait` - what's wrong with `setTimeout`?

Comment: I am still learning, so I want to ensure I know as much alternative ways as possible

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can convert `wait()` to an async function an use `await` to postpone the rest of the function's body:

```js
async function wait() {
    await true;
    let a = Date.now()
    while (Date.now() - a < 3000) {
        //loop
    }
    console.log('waiting ends...')
}
function start(){
    console.log('starts...')
    wait();
}
function end(){
    console.log('ends...')
}

start()
end()
```

Or you can do it with `start()`:

```js
function wait() {
    let a = Date.now()
    while (Date.now() - a < 3000) {
        //loop
    }
    console.log('waiting ends...')
}
async function start(){
    await console.log('starts...')
    wait();
}
function end(){
    console.log('ends...')
}

start()
end()
```

You can use `queueMicrotask()` to execute a function as a microtask (the same as immediately resolving a promise):

```js
function wait() {
    let a = Date.now()
    while (Date.now() - a < 3000) {
        //loop
    }
    console.log('waiting ends...')
}
function start(){
    console.log('starts...')
    queueMicrotask(wait);
}
function end(){
    console.log('ends...')
}

start()
end()
```